# I want to upgrade eclipse indigo(3.7) to eclipse luna(4.4.2)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mylyn-wikitext

I have around 15 plugins whcih is developed in eclipse juno.
If i try to import all the plugin projects to eclipse luna.
I am getting lot of exception.
Eg: As i read in few sites that some of the API's which are in eclipse indigo, has been removed in luna.
One such example is org.eclipse.update.core.
But my problem is that while developing the code in indigo, they have used that API, so i am getting some exception.

Apart from this i have problem in Mylyn, EPIC(Perl development) as well.
Can anyone please suggest me some steps Or procedure which i should follow to to build a new eclipse product by using eclipse luna.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, add some concrete error messages instead of generally saying it does not work. It makes very hard to figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to follow this way [How to share plugins across multiple Eclipse installations and reinstall Eclipse easily](http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2009/12/16/the-easy-way-to-reinstall-eclipse-and-share-plugins-across-multiple-installations/).
Also you can try to use this [Yatta profiles](https://marketplace.yatta.de/profiles/) plugin.
I think  **yatta** will be better solution.